# meta language attribute href language for russian speaking countries

Tags: language, hreflang

I didn't find a specific answer to my questions in my search.
i have a website, and I need to target Russia and neighbouring countries ( Moldova, Ukraine, Belarus, Kazakhstan, etc..)

My website is only in Russian language and those countries all speak and understand Russian. I need an href language to insert in my  that defines russian language to these countries and refer to my main website.
is it possible? can anyone help? 
thanks to all who respond to my question .

Comment: Sorry but this question appears to be off topic because there is already various questions and answers on Pro Webmasters regarding the use of a single spoken language while targeting multiple countries.

Comment: im going to be more precise since i think that my question was vague.  `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="http://www.example.com/" />`
`<link rel="alternate" hreflang="rus" href="http://www.example.com/" />`
`<link rel="alternate" hreflang="rus-ua" href="http://www.example.com/" />`.   is this code applicable? they all link to the same main page. i am just defining to search engines that the page is in Russian and it is available for Ukraine , Moldova.........

Comment: to be more precise. can all of my href lang link to a single page ? or different versions of a page should be made?